# How can I set the view / world matrices in SlimDX / DirectX11

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx, directx-11

I'm trying to implement a simple FPS camera, that I have brought over from an older XNA Project, in SlimDX.Direct3D11. I have no idea how to set the resulting view matrix, or any matrix for that matter.

All tutorials I have found use C++ and functions or classes that are not available in SlimDX. Do any of you know know more of more examples than the three on the SlimDX homepage?

This is my vertex shader

```
cbuffer MatrixBuffer
{
    matrix worldMatrix;
    matrix viewMatrix;
    matrix projectionMatrix;
};

struct VertexInputType
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};
PixelInputType TextureVertexShader(VertexInputType input)
{
    PixelInputType output;

    input.position.w = 1.0f;

    output.position = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

    output.tex = input.tex;

    return output;
}
```

And loading them with

```
bytecode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("shader/triangle.fx", "TextureVertexShader", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.None, EffectFlags.None);
inputSignature = ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(bytecode);
vertexShader = new VertexShader(device, bytecode);
```

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962225/setting-up-the-constant-buffer-using-slimdx. You'll need to make a constant buffer, fill it with the values you want, and then bind it to your vertex shader.